# How to filter-out error-page links when scraping Ebay product-pages?

Tags: python, filter, beautifulsoup, href

I built a bot in Python that scrapes **eBay product listing links** from HTML.

Every link is pointing to the *product page*.
However, the first one is pointing to an **error page** like:

```
https://www.ebay.com/itm/01920391?epid=26039819083&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item3b542eae7a:g:FQkAAOSwK21gKvEZ&amdata=enc%3AAQAFAAACcBaobrjLl8XobRIiIML1V4Imu%252Fn%252BzU5L90Z278x5ickkrDx%252B2NLp21dg6hHbHAkGMYdiW1E6zjXxnQ0bf7c%252Fx%252Fvs5PW%252FYFw1ZdbGMi8wsGV6qXw8OFLl4Os1ACX3bnQxFkVpRib9hMb5gVyLha4q9L0xiporu5InbX0LrSgg7nCCCwtC7y3vOE3hc8PszsrXWLb5KFdj7%252BD98et12MdkEfMPFhJZuS%252BkFsp2esVTRCYctOhcwzPSdfzCOYprlr2miQc4czCv1Tcfs3LKUPJn8uQyRc%252BAnKY1oyTeYnJ7wYuGkBU%252FSVYjziLBaPhT%252FlVu0hR9ZX6OnAeRaJ1g0iCaDjrRXEXRwUO87riWeI8kExm1zzY7QicPeMnfWZdBvVhg05GOScPOlLTVPHakqGLX0y2GUXV6fkTLua3nSF5YBmLX%252FqdCxT6yS0dutVs5MPWvQYlN474hUzbubkZVAs7Y%252BBBEsHrGjVzCj0szZ6w1%252BHgkV5O9jrXGnyew5%252Bnxy7VCq5xEkUDIt1nSg996AeDksNmSNumhfsIOGltIXbqAbjqEUpPcVO%252BDPymxlh0iMxCZQalYnmljBRzKILYWkES0vfA14Gh5E7KWrztdC6WzEEFtgVuABakQ1eAOZnuEueqK6IakC%252BIfRbXv96Tv01IPDvwPeM8wMo6j8bMjY3D5KHS5EXPVdHKUnjCJiYCcVUqcKwhL6eN2MZ%252Bn9yxmWESUPN394NPrX%252FI2z7t0Bbo7iqmsWNQcyi0EHzDwJPMK%252FNSif8%252F2adRF7dT1JrbL9sryKSN2kv9OsdGQ0fMMC1LV3Ph43HivUJdqkgjGxqEqX5v1xQ%253D%253D%7Ccksum%3A25481541593068896952f4834d93a0bb998f5b5ba5fe%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524
```

#### Code

```py
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/admin/eBay/chromedriver')

#error = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/div/p")


url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=New+Big+Frame+Square+Sunglasses+Fashion+Trend+All-match+Women%27s+Sunglasses+Cross-border+Hot+Sale+Sunglasses&_sacat=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.select("li a")

for a in listings:
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/"):
        page = browser.get(link)
```

How can I remove or ignore the *error-page* link?

Comment: You can use this selector `#srp-river-results li.s-item a.s-item__link[href]` to get rid of that unwanted link in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip first link you can use list slicing with `[1:]`:

```py
...

for a in listings[1:]:  # <--- ignore first link
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/"):
        page = browser.get(link)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would have gone similar way to @SIM and relied on faster css filtering and using css classes (generally 2nd fastest way of matching on nodes in css after id).

```
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('#srp-river-results .s-item__link')]
```

The introduction of the leading id limits results to the actual listings block.

If you are somehow worried that urls with other start strings might occur, which seems unlikely given the consistent design of these pages, you can add in a css attribute = value selector with ^ starts with operator:

```
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('#srp-river-results .s-item__link[href^="https://www.ebay.com/itm/"]')]
```

In case of wanting more info then set listings as

```
listings = soup.select('#srp-river-results .s-item')
```

Then access links with:

```
links = [listing.select_one('.s-item__link[href^="https://www.ebay.com/itm/"]')['href'] for listing in listings]
```

Answer (score 1):

cut out that link using the if statement

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')

#error = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/div/p")


url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=New+Big+Frame+Square+Sunglasses+Fashion+Trend+All-match+Women%27s+Sunglasses+Cross-border+Hot+Sale+Sunglasses&_sacat=0"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features="lxml")

listings = soup.select("li a")
b=1

error_page ='https://www.ebay.com/itm/01920391?epid=26039819083&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item3b542eae7a:g:FQkAAOSwK21gKvEZ&amdata=enc%3AAQAFAAACcBaobrjLl8XobRIiIML1V4Imu%252Fn%252BzU5L90Z278x5ickkrDx%252B2NLp21dg6hHbHAkGMYdiW1E6zjXxnQ0bf7c%252Fx%252Fvs5PW%252FYFw1ZdbGMi8wsGV6qXw8OFLl4Os1ACX3bnQxFkVpRib9hMb5gVyLha4q9L0xiporu5InbX0LrSgg7nCCCwtC7y3vOE3hc8PszsrXWLb5KFdj7%252BD98et12MdkEfMPFhJZuS%252BkFsp2esVTRCYctOhcwzPSdfzCOYprlr2miQc4czCv1Tcfs3LKUPJn8uQyRc%252BAnKY1oyTeYnJ7wYuGkBU%252FSVYjziLBaPhT%252FlVu0hR9ZX6OnAeRaJ1g0iCaDjrRXEXRwUO87riWeI8kExm1zzY7QicPeMnfWZdBvVhg05GOScPOlLTVPHakqGLX0y2GUXV6fkTLua3nSF5YBmLX%252FqdCxT6yS0dutVs5MPWvQYlN474hUzbubkZVAs7Y%252BBBEsHrGjVzCj0szZ6w1%252BHgkV5O9jrXGnyew5%252Bnxy7VCq5xEkUDIt1nSg996AeDksNmSNumhfsIOGltIXbqAbjqEUpPcVO%252BDPymxlh0iMxCZQalYnmljBRzKILYWkES0vfA14Gh5E7KWrztdC6WzEEFtgVuABakQ1eAOZnuEueqK6IakC%252BIfRbXv96Tv01IPDvwPeM8wMo6j8bMjY3D5KHS5EXPVdHKUnjCJiYCcVUqcKwhL6eN2MZ%252Bn9yxmWESUPN394NPrX%252FI2z7t0Bbo7iqmsWNQcyi0EHzDwJPMK%252FNSif8%252F2adRF7dT1JrbL9sryKSN2kv9OsdGQ0fMMC1LV3Ph43HivUJdqkgjGxqEqX5v1xQ%253D%253D%7Ccksum%3A25481541593068896952f4834d93a0bb998f5b5ba5fe%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524'
for a in listings:
    
    link = a["href"]
    if link.startswith("https://www.ebay.com/itm/") and link !=error_page:

        page = browser.get(link)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thenujan, it is working perfectly!